# Python: looping through a list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a list, example:

```
mylist=["a", "b", "end"]
```

I want to append all values of mylist to a different list (new_list) and also add the string " letter" to each value of the new_list except the last one (value: end)

So far I have a for loop that adds the string "letter" to all values:

```
new_list = []

for x in my_list:
   new_list.append(x + " letter")
```

which produces:

> ("a letter", "b letter", "end letter")

I want:

> ("a letter", "b letter", "end")

Comment: Why does the list contain `'end'`? Simply having the list terminate would arguably be much clearer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is best achieved with list comprehensions and slicing:

```
>>> new_list = [s + ' letter' for s in mylist[:-1]] + mylist[-1:]
>>> new_list
['a letter', 'b letter', 'end']
```

Comment: Hmm, all these temporary lists... avoids the temporaries - `[s + ' letter' if i < len(mylist)-1 else s for i, s in enumerate(mylist)]` but equally ugly.

Answer (score 2):

We have to skip the last element, use list slices for this; using a list comprehension will also come in handy. Try this:

```
mylist   = ['a', 'b', 'end']
new_list = [x + ' letter' for x in mylist[:-1]] + [mylist[-1]]
```

It works as expected:

```
new_list
=> ['a letter', 'b letter', 'end']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `" letter"` to each of your element in a list except the last one, and then just add the last one.

```
new_list = [x + " letter" for x in my_list[:-1]] + [my_list[-1]]
```